# how to connect apple TV without giving my mac address

Tags: appletv

i got my Apple TV with me cause i live in hotel but the only way to connected to internet if i give them my mac address, therefore if i give my mac address to customer service wont they be able to access all my info? and my mobile when connected? or pictures and video.

Comment: A MAC address is not a password, it is an identifier of the machine connecting to their network. It's analogous to giving the hotel the license plate of your car (in order to park in their lot), not like giving them the keys to your car.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect to a network, by any means, it knows your MAC.
I assume they want this to only allow connection from known devices.

There is no risk (or at least no more than any other connection). You just need to use normal security procedures.